# Why do I get special characters in my Notepad++ macros?

Tags: notepad++, macros

Ok so every time I go to make a macro for `<br />` I wind up getting special characters because of the shift button and such

this is what I wind up getting when I run the macro after just plainly typing `<br />`

```
<ûbrû />û
```

Comment: And your question?

Comment: What is the macro supposed to do?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug which is fixed in 5.8.2.  Time to upgrade!

Comment: [Release information](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/release/5.8.2)

Answer (score 1):

From just looking at your output it looks like your macro was recorded using a multi-byte character set and the current document you're running it does not support multi-byte characters.  Try switching your current document format to UTF-8.